# Generate Jenkins Encrypted Password With PowerShell or DOS

Tags: jenkins

For login to Jenkins we are using Active Directory plugin. The LDAP Domain connection requires to authentication. So we include the bindName and bindPassword in the config.xml file.

After the password for the bindName account is changed, we can no longer log into Jenkins (to update the password).

We need a tool to generate the jenkins encrypted password without logging into Jenkins.

I think this could be done with a [java](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/developer/security/secrets/) program. But I am not a java programmer.